# Precompiling application.js assets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I get this code in my application.js working so that I can precompile the images used here? What rails helper should I be using?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".imgthumb").click(function(){
        $(".thumbnailcurrent").addClass("thumbnails");
        $(".thumbnails").removeClass("thumbnailcurrent");
        $(this).addClass("thumbnailcurrent");
        $(this).removeClass("thumbnails");

        var img=($(this).attr("data-id"));

        if (img==1) {

         $('.imgbig').html("<%= asset_path src: 'flappy1.jpg', height: '275', width: '391' %>");
        } else if (img==2) {

         $('.imgbig').html("<%= asset_path src: 'flappy2.jpg', height: '275', width: '391' %>");
        } else if (img==3) {

         $('.imgbig').html("<%= asset_path src: 'flappy3.jpg', height: '275', width: '391' %>");
        }


});

    });
```

Comment: When you say "precompile the images", do you mean you want to _preload_ them from JS?

Comment: I'd just like the above code to work ultimately.. It's stored in the applications.js.erb file.. does it look right to you? Not sure if I setup the asset_path and src: implemention correctly. A second pair of eyes will be great, thanks so much.

Comment: Maybe
$('.imgbig').html("<img src='#{asset_path('flappy1.jpg')}' height='275px' width='391px>");

Comment: Hey, I think that I understand your problem. Maybe, this is what you need? https://github.com/kavkaz/js_assets

Comment: Yeah basically the images show in development but not in production.. will that gem do the trick? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Precompiled images located in public/assets path? Why not use this path directly?

Comment: Thanks so much Vitaly, that's fair enough but does the code above look functional? I have a gallery and with the above code the images still aren't switching want to make sure it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access your assets by url:

```
'/assets/images/flappy1.png'
```

because in production environment you have something like:

`'/assets/images/flappy1-b3bb250d5300736006c894.png'`

The table of compliance between them lies in manifest-file, that generates automatically.

However, using of manifest-file directly is a bad idea, because in contains many of extraneous data.

Generally you has two options:

1. Wrap your javascript with Erb preprocessor, to have access to

   `<%= asset_path(path/to/asset.jpg) %>` helper.
2. Or more beauty solution: **gem 'js_assets'**, that solve your problem.

After gem install, you need include JavaScript-helper:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require app_assets
```

Table of compliance will be stored in **window.project_assets** variable.

**asset_path** javascript's helper method receives logical path to your asset, and returns relative path, given existent environment:

```
var path = asset_path('images/flappy1.jpg')
// the function will return for development:
// /images/flappy1.jpg
// and for production
// /assets/images/flappy1-b3bb250d5300736006c894.jpg
```

Hope, this helps!